# Where are all the collectibles located?

Tags: dead-island

I just found my first collectible ingame. I noticed that there are various achievements associated with finding all of the collectibles. Is there a list with the locations of all the collectibles? So I know what I'm looking for, are they all recordings or will they be other items as well?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a complete list of the collectibles ordered by area:

#### Resort

*There are 39 collectibles in Resort area.*

- Roof of Tunnel Gas Station, in a tool box. (**ID CARD**)
- West to the resort, there is a wrecked truck next to the road. Search its dash board. (**ID CARD**)
- Next to the bed, Harlan’s hut. (**Banoi Herald Excerpt**)
- At the northwest section of the Resort, get into the bunker and search above the bench. The bunker is locked until Act 2. (**Banoi Herald Excerpt**)
- Right after you enter into the warehouse, take a right and search near the desk. There is an ID card just next to the lamp. (**ID Card**)
- Search above the workbench of the warehouse. (**Banoi Herald Excerpt**)
- Look at the roof of the building, there is a sign which says "Help". Just next to that sign is some luggage, search in there. (**ID CARD 16**)
- Back room of the warehouse, next to a lamp of the desk. (**ID CARD**)
- Gas Station, just next to the cash counter/register (**ID CARD**)
- Search the luggage bag which is lying in front of the entrance to the hotel. (**ID CARD**)
- Search for a key on the bars which are next to the entrances of the hut (next to the hotel) and then enter into the hut and look for the card. (**ID CARD**)
- Women’s bathrooms (underground). It’s lying on the corner in an open bag.
- On the bookshelf of the Bungalow 15, use the side door to get in. (**ID CARD**)
- Grab the keys from a corpse lying in front of the hotel entrance and then enter into the bungalow number 14. The card is on a bed. (**ID CARD 22**)
- Sinamoi’s bungalow, on a table. (**TAPE**)
- Steve Summer’s Bungalow, jump over the barrier to get in. (**ID CARD**)
- Outside the bungalow 4, search the suitcase. (**ID CARD**)
- In the hut, right after the prologue when you begin the game. (**BANOI HERALD EXCERPT**)
- Surf Shop, next to the computer. (**BANOI HERALD EXCERPT**)
- In the bar hut, end of the pier. (**ID CARD**)
- First Floor – Lifeguard Tower, search the desk. (**Banoi Herald Excerpt**)
- Red Bungalow, on the bed room’s desk. (**Banoi Herald Excerpt**)
- The Bungalow where you meet Anne. (**Banoi Herald Excerpt**)
- Same Bungalow, on the nightstand. (**ID CARD**)
- If you have done the quests you’ll see Luke Craig, just next to him is a bookshelf. There is the card. (**ID CARD**)
- Search the bedroom of the bungalow, enter from the side door if front is locked. (**ID CARD**)
- PowerStation (underground), search the toolbox lying at the corner. (**Banoi Herald Excerpt**)
- There is a lifeguard hut on the beach, search its windowsill. (**ID CARD**)
- Blue beach Tower, beach (**ID CARD**)
- The bungalow near the beach, on the table. (**ID CARD**)
- Music Stage, next to the table top fan. (**ID CARD**)
- On the table next to JAMES. (**TAPE**)
- On the top floor of the bunker, search the desk. (**Banoi Herald Excerpt**)
- Inside the bunker, on the crates. (**ID CARD**)
- In the northeastern bungalow of the resort, search the shelves. (**Banoi Herald Excerpt**)
- Lying on the ground of the bar hut. (**ID CARD**)
- On the bathroom table of the bungalow. (**ID CARD**)
- Lying on the bed of this bungalow. (**ID CARD**)
- On the counter of the bar hut. (**Banoi Herald Excerpt**)

#### Parking Lot

*Once you trigger the quest "Born to be wild", collect all of the quests because once it’s finished. Many of the areas will be locked and you will not be able to collect many of the collectibles. There are 10 collectibles in Parking Lot area.*

- Go straight after entering into the hotel and search on the couch which is next to the elevator. (**ID CARD**)
- There is a small room which has a chair lying on the ground (backwards), next to a zombie. The collectible is on the table. This room comes before the gift shop. (**Banoi Herald Excerpt**)
- You will see a corpse in front of the door, right after you speak to Davies and drop from the elevator. The card is next to that body. (**ID CARD**)
- There is a freezer room of the Kitchen, meat is hanging over there. Search next to the corpse. (**ID CARD**)
- You will exit the kitchen if you keep on following the main path, once you do keep looking for a luggage cart. (**Banoi Herald Excerpt**)
- The double door exit of the bathroom area, search the shelves which are in-between the showers and toilet area. (**ID CARD**)
- The room where you find Ken’s Morphine, search the desk of the corner. (**Banoi Herald Excerpt**)
- A double-door will be unlocked once Ken dies, enter and head towards the office. Search the desk on your left. (**Banoi Herald Excerpt**)
- After 47, go to the lounge and look on the small table just next to the windows. (**TAPE**)
- Server Room, first desk. (**ID CARD**)

#### Moresby

*There are 27 collectibles in Moresby area.*

- Behind the counter of the restaurant (**ID CARD**)
- On the wooden patio tables (**Banoi Excerpt**)
- On the shelf, next to the vending machine. Agdat Shop. (**Tape**)
- Near the bridge, next to the up-side down car. (**ID CARD**)
- The house where you kill Mugambas wife (abandoned house), next to the toilet (**BANOI EXCERPT**)
- It is next to the fire hydrant, lying on the small table. (main street)
- Talk to Vang Chi and trigger the "Heroes and Villains" quest. He is standing on the southeast area of the pumping station. You will find this ID on the table, just before you meet her daughter. (**ID CARD**)
- Lying on a table, next to the wrecked ambulance on the main street. (**BOSTON HERALD EXCERPT**)
- Gas station’s counter. (**ID CARD**)
- Collect this after you have triggered the "Picture of Bliss" quest. It is inside the store’s counter. (**ID CARD**)
- If you enter the alley from the North then you’ll find it lying on the floor. (**ID CARD**)
- On the rooftop, search for a ladder on the North. (**TAPE**)
- Second floor of the church, next to Raymond lying on a mattress. (**Banoi Herald Excerpt**)
- Abandoned house, you can enter this house only when the quest "uninvited guests" is going on, so collect it from the shelf which is next to the door.
- Back Alley, mattress (**ID CARD**)
- On the table, just next to the workbench. (**Banoi Herald Excerpt**)
- On the roof of the building, Search the north-side and look for a ladder. (**ID CARD**)
- Quest (A new broom sweeps clean), abandoned house, the first room you get to after entering in from the roof, search near the bunk beds. (**Banoi Herald Excerpt**)
- Bathroom of the house mentioned in number 67. (**ID CARD**)
- In front of the door, right after completing the A new Broom sweeps clean quest. (**ID CARD**)
- Abandoned house, 2nd floor bedroom. You get access here once the "grasp all, lose all" side-quest is triggered. (**ID CARD**)
- Search the table which is in-between the two chairs. (**ID CARD**)
- Another abandoned house is linked to the Blood Ties quest, enter and walk into the room on your right and search the tables. (**ID CARD**)
- Lying on the ground, between the chair and the tank. (**ID CARD**)
- In the shop, next to the vending machine…on the shelf (**Banoi Herald Excerpt**)
- Search for a ladder which leads you to the roof area, and look onto the mattress nearby. (**ID CARD**)
- Near the sewer entrances, off the road is a small table. (**ID CARD**)

#### Sewers

*There are nine collectibles in Sewers area.*

- At front of the control panel, lying on the desk. (**ID CARD**)
- In the "Let the Waters Flow" objective, you will activate a control panel and after that you’ll get into a place where you will have a choice to either choose the left door or the right door, choose the right one and head straight until you reach to a room which has a workbench with this. (**Banoi Herald Excerpt**)
- The same quest as 78, you will get into a floater. Once you get off look on the left side and enter into that door. Search the luggage (open bag). (**ID CARD**)
- Look for a workbench after 79, this is on the bench. (**ID CARD**)
- Supermarket Journey, you will get back to the sewer from the city hall – in some toxic water. Search for a ladder and go up. (**ID CARD**)
- Market
- This card is lying on the desk of the office which is on the left side of the double doors – the entrance to main market room. (**ID CARD**)
- There is a desk which looks like a reception, look next to the phone. (**ID CARD**)
- When you get into the kitchen, search the tables. (**Banoi Herald Excerpt**)
- The room you get into after the kitchen, search the bookshelves. (**Banoi Herald Excerpt**)

#### City Hall

*These are no collectable until the Bitter End quest. After that you can collect 3.*

- Search beside the lockers, you’ll get to them once you cross the first set of winding chairs. (**ID CARD**)
- Go to the 2nd floor once you have collected the universal key. Get inside the small office and search the desk (**ID CARD**)
- You will get into a room which has a thug and a workbench, at the end of the Bitter End. Look at the bulletin board. (**ID CARD**)

#### Police Station

*There are six collectibles in Police Station area.*

- Police Station Garage, dead cop. (**TAPE**)
- Just next to bill, at the end of the hallway. (**ID CARD**)
- It is down the hall of the last collectible, lying on a table/camera. (**Banoi Herald Excerpt**)
- First Floor, check the desk of the room which is fully guarded by the thugs. (**ID CARD**)
- 2nd floor, go past the over-turned file cabinet and enter into the right-side room. Search the tables. (**Banoi Herald Excerpt**)
- The last room, BIG one. It is where you fight off some thugs. See the cabins on the right side and look for a dead cop. (**ID CARD**)

#### Jungle

*17 collectibles to retrieve from Jungle area.*

- Jason’s House – Jason is a serious threat though fast movement and heavy attacks. Try to run and climb up the ladder into the house. Collect the card and the chainsaw to take care of Jason. (**ID CARD**)
- Search the coffee table of the last house on the left side, village. (**ID CARD**)
- The warehouse is locked first, do the quest "Visit the Pub" by talking to the man sitting outside and then collect the card from the shelf inside. (**ID CARD**)
- It’s on the bar of the building where you find the mechanic in the quest of "Visit the Pub" (**ID CARD**)
- Climb onto the roof and jump down into the next hut, it’s on the stool. (**ID CARD**)
- Enter into this hut by climbing up to the bridge and then jumping onto the roof. Collect the card from the table. (**ID CARD**)
- Control Room, Bulletin Board. (**ID CARD**)
- Village, first house on left. Search the Cofee table. (**Banoi Herald Excerpt**)
- Search the bus situated in the middle of the village. (**ID CARD**)
- The table next to the workbench. (**Banoi Herald Excerpt**)
- The hut of Carter, search the bed. (**ID CARD**)
- Main hut of the village, desk. (**TAPE**)
- This is the hut in which you enter while doing the "The dead in fishing net" quest. It’s on the eastern river-side. Look at the table, next to the bed. (**ID CARD**)
- Enter into the bunker and climb the next ladder, its next to a backpack. (**ID CARD**)
- When you are climbing the passenger cabin of the airliner, search the id card on the seats where cargo is scattered. (**ID CARD**)
- Search by the steering wheel of the bus. (**Banoi Herald Excerpt**)
- Mowen’s hut, table. This is only accessed after the "King of the Swamp" quest.

#### LAB

*There are 19 collectibles in this area.*

- Enter into the building (lab) and climb the stairs, the card is in front of a door. (**ID CARD**)
- There is a truck next to the road, search the driver’s seat. (**ID CARD**)
- Lying next to a corpse, lab’s driveway. (**ID CARD**)
- Search the coffee table, the one which comes before Will opens the door for you. (**Banoi Herald Excerpt**)
- The toilets search the tank of the left toilet. These toilets are next to Will. (**Banoi Herald Excerpt**)
- Search Bob’s desk, it comes before you enter into the Dr.West Lab. (**Tape**)
- In the "Rats in the Lab" quest, when Bob opens up a door for you. Head in and enter into the first room on the right side, search the desks. (**Banoi Herald Excerpt**)
- There is a stack of crates on which you can climb and jump over the fence to get into the warehouse, the card is on the computer desk. (**ID CARD**)
- This is on the edge of the catwalk; you can go down the metal stairs and continue your way towards here. (**ID CARD**)
- The first desk you see after entering into the ware house. (**Tape**)
- Trigger the "Scran’s out for the Dead" from the lab (this is only done if you have already accepted the "Pure Blood" quest) and then enter into the warehouse, the card is lying in the corner. (**ID CARD**)
- The lab which had a barricade around it is now enterable. This is after you come back from the warrior’s base. Search the desk next to Monroe. (**ID CARD**)
- This is the building where you get access once you are doing the "Rotten Flesh" mission, after completing the "Man of Faith" come back and search the desks. (**ID CARD**)
- Near the foot of the bed. (**Banoi Herald Excerpt**)
- Search the bathrooms. (**ID CARD**)
- After accepting "Pure Blood" quest, go to the Connor’s cabin and search the small tables. (**Banoi Herald Excerpt**)
- Get inside by jumping down from the roof, search the bathrooms. (**ID CARD**)
- Get in from the roof by breaking the skylight. Search the chairs. (**ID CARD**)
- Search the counter, next to the phone. (building). (**ID CARD**)

#### Prison

*There are 30 collectibles in this area but before you come here, make sure you have unlocked all the collectibles achievements, because you won’t be able to go back from this area.*

- There is an "O" painted on the wall, see the metal bench next to it. (**TAPE**)
- The Green Mile mission – when Alvaro will show you a thug who’ll be blocking your path, take him out and search that room’s desk. (**ID CARD**)
- You will get access to the 2nf floor by the "Full Metal Jacket" quest. Climb up and enter into the medical room (right). Search the desks. (**ID CARD**)
- Once you leave the Medical Room, you’ll cross multiple doors and reach to a door which is locked, the item is lying next to that door. (**Banoi Herald Excerpt**)
- The room next to the workbench room has this collectible. It is collected after all the doors are opened by Kevin. (**ID CARD**)
- After accepting the "Dante’s Kitchen" quest, enter into the kitchen store room and search for a dad cop lying next to a wall. The card is just next to him. (**ID CARD**)
- Metal Table, Kitchen. (**ID CARD**)
- You will go to the basement in the "Devil’s Labyrinth". Search next to the control panel (**ID CARD**)
- Once you reach to the workbench in the basement, look for it. (**ID CARD**)
- There is a thug next to the stair-case, after you cross the laundry. Kill him and collect the card which is just next to him. (**ID CARD**)
- Before entering into the sewers, see behind the stair-case. "Devil’s Labyrinth". (**ID CARD**)
- In the sewers, where you see the first floater, search next to it (right). (**ID CARD**)
- As soon as your objective changed to go up. Keep moving forward instead of taking the ladders and look beside the cop. (Sewers). (**ID CARD**)
- Turn around after you climb up the ladders to exit the Sewers. (**ID CARD**)
- You will get to a point where there is a chest and some ammunition next to a winding set of stairs. Go up from there and search on the mattress, Chasing the White Rabbit. (**ID CARD**)
- Search the desk of the first room on the left, 2nd level. (**ID CARD**)
- On the bed of the same location (**TAPE**)
- Take a left from the room of #146,147. Follow that wall and it will lead you to a corpse which has this Tape. (**TAPE**)
- You will reach to a hallway on the right side, if following the main corridor. Go downwards and enter into the room on your left, search the desks. (**Banoi Herald Excerpt**)
- Main corridor, search the beds of the rooms on the left side of the Corridor. (**ID CARD**)

**All credits goes to [segmentnext.com](http://segmentnext.com/2011/09/06/dead-island-collectibles-guide/) for their list.**

Comment: That list seems to be complete now. Could you put the list in the article here as well so we don't lose it to link rot? I'll accept then. :)

Comment: @FallenAngelEyes Done :)