# Where is the voice recording #4 in Dead Island?

Tags: dead-island

I just came across #5, but the last one I found was #3. I looked through most of the quest locations in the city already, but I can't find it.

Where is recording #4?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where are all the collectibles located?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/29996/where-are-all-the-collectibles-located)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It took me a while, but I found it. It's in a strange location considering that quests will lead you to #5 much quicker than to #4.

Anyways, part of the "Head of Cerberus" missions will lead you to the rooftops of the center of the city. Next to one of the speakers (the last one) that you need to activate there will be a recording on the floor: #4.